# php create function from string value

Tags: php, user-defined-functions

I just simply want to create a function name with a string value.

Something like this:

```
$ns = 'test';
function $ns.'_this'(){}
test_this();
```

It of course throws an error.

I've tried with:

```
function {$ns}.'_this'
function {$ns.'_this'}
```

but no luck.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *not* possible. If all you want to do is, to prefix all functions with some common string, maybe you want to use namespaces?

```
namespace foo {
    function bar() {}
    function rab() {}
    function abr() {}
}
// access from global namespace is as follows:
namespace {
    foo\bar(); foo\rab(); foo\abr();
}
```

Comment: ehhh, I had already been down that road with namespaces.  I tell you, php namespaces are terrible.  Anyways, I guess that's what I wanted to know was that it CANNOT be done.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) to create a function from provided string.

**Example (php.net)**

```
<?php
$newfunc = create_function('$a,$b', 'return "ln($a) + ln($b) = " . log($a * $b);');
echo "New anonymous function: $newfunc\n";
echo $newfunc(2, M_E) . "\n";
// outputs
// New anonymous function: lambda_1
// ln(2) + ln(2.718281828459) = 1.6931471805599
?>
```

Comment: Right, I looked at that. I would still like to be able to call the function in the traditional manner, which this doesn't allow for.

Comment: ^`create_function()` removed in PHP8+

Answer (score 2):

file with function (`somefile.php`)

```
function outputFunctionCode($function_name)
{?>
    function <?php echo $function_name ?>()
    {
    //your code
    }
<?php }
```

file with code which "declares" the function:

```
ob_start();
include("somefile.php");
outputFunctionCode("myDynamicFunction");
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$file = fopen("somefile2.php", "w");
fwrite($file,$contents);
fclose($file);
include("somefile2.php");
```

It is ugly, but then again, it is an extremely bad idea to declare functions with dynamic names.

Comment: Agreed, ugly as can be, but it does do what the OP asked

Answer (score 1):

using "eval" is not a good practice, but that may serve the purpose similar to your requirements sometimes.

```
   <?php

 $ns = 'test';
 $funcName = $ns.'_this';
    eval("function $funcName(){ echo 1;}");
    test_this();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<?php

function foo($a) {   print 'foo called'.$a; }

$myfunctionNameStr = 'foo';

$myfunctionNameStr(2);

?>
```

Cause i don't think that you can dynamically construct a function declaration. You can decide at 'runtime' the value of the $myfunctionNameStr though.